# How to use ag-grid license

Tags: ag-grid

How to insert license key in ag-grid? Reading https://www.ag-grid.com/license-pricing.php it details pricing. Where is license key to be placed, is as part of request ? Or license just to ask support type questions and I can use the library itself without ?

Comment: Be sure to read the actual license at https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise/blob/master/LICENSE.md.  JS devs must be licensed even if they never work on ag-grid.  All public websites are considered SaaS, even free ones.  The full license is charged every year you want updates.  Make sure you understand the full cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some features of the grid are enterprise only. In the features menu on the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-license/), the only things that are enterprise only are marked with a circled e. [Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-license/) you can find information about setting the license for your particular framework.